# Subtracting/Removing Days from Date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of ~ 8000 rows with dates, from which I would like to remove the days part in some way or another:

Start:

```
df2[['day','shifted_date']].head(3)

 day    shifted_date
  31    2015-03-31
  28    2015-02-28
  14    2015-01-14
```

End 1 :

```
df2[['day','shifted_date']].head(3)

`day    shifted_date`
  31    2015-03-01
  28    2015-02-01
  14    2015-01-01
```

or End 2 :

```
df2[['day','shifted_date']].head(3)

`day    shifted_date`
  31    2015-03
  28    2015-02
  14    2015-01
```

I've been messing around with these, which don't work as they don't take arrays/slices as input as far as I can figure:

```
   # timedelta(days=df2['day'])
   # datetime.date(df2['year'], df2['month'],31)
```

So what I would really like is

```
 df2[['shifted_date']] = magicalfunction.df2[['day','shifted_date']]
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas dataframe will return to you a date object, which you can just format into what you need instead of doing date math with timedelta:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date(2015,3,31)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('{0.year}-{0.month}'.format(d), '%Y-%m')
datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 0)
```